# react, setState and having components re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app, I'm trying to achieve the results of toggling background colors of a graph, even if a graph is already loaded/rendered on screen.

With my current code, if I click the checkbox to toggle the colors it works perfectly fine as far as setting the colors in state and passing those into my component, but I have to reload the component on screen to see the changes, but they do show at that point.

I've tried to use forceUpdate() to rectify this but to no avail

What should I do at this point to make sure that when the state changes in this function it reloads the component completely?

```
state = {
  renderCalories: true,
  graphBackgroundColor: '#fff',
  graphLabelColor: '#000'

};


toggleCOlor = event => {
  console.log('toggling color');
  this.setState({
   graphBackgroundColor: '#000',
   graphLabelColor: '#fff'
  });
 this.forceUpdate();
}
render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <div className={styles.dropDown}>
     <FormControl style={{minWidth: 120}} className={styles.formControl}>
      <FormControlLabel
        value="end"
        control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
        label="Toggle Graph Background Color"
        labelPlacement="end"
        onChange={this.toggleCOlor}
      />
      </FormControl>
    </div>

  {this.state.renderCalories && <NetCalorieTrend backgroundColor={this.state.graphBackgroundColor} labelColor={this.state.graphLabelColor} />}

...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem at all, but you shouldn't use the forceUpdate method, because when you set a new state the component got rendered, so you are update the component twice , the second render is not necessary

Comment: can you give more context of what you want to achieve

Comment: @JuorderGonzalez when the page loads it renders the component above, so when I load the page and toggle the colors I don't see the color change until I manually re-render the component again with a dropdown box. I just want to immediately show the changed colors

Comment: Tom if your component don't updated when you setState, so maybe you NetCalorieTrend component have some memo or it's a pureComponent, can you write de code for the NetCalorieTrend component ?

Comment: The component file for that is rather large, is there a part of it that would be most helpful?

Comment: @JuorderGonzalez I also kind of figured this has something to do with the component only rendering based on the state of renderCalories. Would it be more beneficial to reset that state?

Comment: Sorry Tom, can you put the code in something like a jsfiddle or better use a codesandbox for react app, it's hard to help you in a blinded way, it seems that your NetCalorieTrend component seems to be the problem

Comment: when state changes, component automatically rerenders.